# How to reduce SoftScore with OptaPlanner and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, optaplanner

I am trying to specify a rule for a soft constraint in my `.drl`-file. It is supposed to take two parameters from the `PlanningSolution` (`Schedule`-class) and then execute a Java-Function with these. Sadly the code seems not to be executed (there is no SoftScore modified, even if I replace the function call `getBlockNumberDifference` with a plain `-10`). Can someone relate to this issue?

I have another rule that specifies a HardConstraint that also uses a function call which is working perfectly fine.

**The Planning Solution:**

```
@PlanningSolution
public class Schedule {
    private Semester semester;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public List<Lecture> getLectureList() {
        return lectureList;
    }

    public void setLectureList(List<Lecture> lectureList) {
        this.lectureList = lectureList;
    }

    public Semester getSemester() {
        return semester;
    }

    public void setSemester(Semester semester) {
        this.semester = semester;
    }
}
```

**The rule:**

```
import function  (...).getBlockNumberDifference;

//...

rule "rule"
    when
        Schedule ( $s : semester != null && $l : lectureList != null)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, getBlockNumberDifference($l, $s));
end
```

**Test:**

```
public static int getBlockNumberDifference(List<Lecture> lectureList, Semester semester) {
        System.out.println("Calling Block number Difference " + lectureList.size() + " and " + semester.getBezeichnung());
        return -1;
}
```

I am using `OptaPlanner` in Version 7.9.0 with Spring Boot and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

The planning solution isn't inserted into the working memory of Drools IIRC, so the LHS (the when side) of that rule never matches.

I might be wrong on this - to prove this, make it `when Schedule() then System.out.println("not in wm");end` and see if you see that appear.